# HP Officejet 4630 printer usb on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, hp, scanner

I need help with installing drivers for HP OfficeJet 4630 printer/scanner on Ubuntu 16.10. Scanning over web interface works fine, and printing test page from physical panel works fine, and also copying work fine, but I am not able to install printing drivers.

I had HPLIP installed (both from APT and .DEB), but printer setup does not show any USB devices attached (despite printer being on and cables connected). I had two options to install as network drivers (one was over DNS and other was over SOCK, vagualy remember) but those did not work. Now I dont see those two options anymore.

Comment: can you type `lsusb` in a terminal please and tell us if the HP is seen and can you type `lpinfo -v` and copy any mention of your HP and paste it back here please; hplip should have been installed by default in ubuntu 16.10 so you shouldn't have needed to install it and your printer only needs version 3.13 and 3.16 is what comes with recent ubuntu; so more than is needed;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install the printer but explanation is doubtful. Instead of using the default WiFi setup I made the device to join an existing SSID, then I was able to find it on the list as a proper network printer. Strage but it somehow worked.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to add a printer is through `CUPS - Common Unix Printing System`.

On my system, I have these `CUPS`-related packages installed, and add my printers via web browser at `http://localhost:631`.

```
$ dpkg -l cups\*| egrep -v '^un'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                      Version              Architecture Description
+++-=========================-====================-============-===================================================================
ii  cups                      2.1.3-4              amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD/driver support, web interface
ii  cups-browsed              1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - cups-browsed
ii  cups-bsd                  2.1.3-4              amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - BSD commands
ii  cups-client               2.1.3-4              amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - client programs (SysV)
ii  cups-common               2.1.3-4              all          Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - common files
ii  cups-core-drivers         2.1.3-4              amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD-less printing
ii  cups-daemon               2.1.3-4              amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - daemon
ii  cups-driver-gutenprint    5.2.10~pre2-0ubuntu2 all          transitional dummy package for gutenprint printer driver
ii  cups-filters              1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Main Package
ii  cups-filters-core-drivers 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1     amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - PPD-less printing
ii  cups-pdf                  2.6.1-21             amd64        PDF writer backend for CUPS (dummy transitional package)
ii  cups-pk-helper            0.2.5-2ubuntu2       amd64        PolicyKit helper to configure cups with fine-grained privileges
ii  cups-ppdc                 2.1.3-4              amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD manipulation utilities
ii  cups-server-common        2.1.3-4              all          Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - server common files
```

After installing `hplip`, monitor the logs via starting `journalctl --follow`, connect the printer/scanner via USB, and point your browser at `http://localhost:631`, `Administration` tab, `Find new printers`

Comment: This method did not find the printer either.

Comment: Does it show up in `lsusb`?

Answer (score 1):

Execute

```
dpkg -l cups\*| egrep -v
```

or remove the old driver before installation.
Try to update to the latest [HP Officejet 4630 Driver](https://www.oplost.com/printer-drivers/hp-officejet-4630-driver-download/).

Find on Linux and go to distro.